# Change value of a UIPageViewController's viewControllerAfterViewController method after a variable has been set?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

I have a UIPageViewController that's working as expected, and it has my child view controllers on each page and everything is great. On one of the pages, I want it so that when a Boolean is set to YES on that child view controller, it allows the user to swipe to the next page. If not, I want them to not be able to proceed forward until the Boolean is set (they should be free to move backwards though).

I set these values in the viewControllerAfterViewController method, but it only gets called when the child view controller is loaded into the UIPageViewController. The way I would like to do it is set this again when the user tries to swipe, but is there a way I can do this without completely overwriting the gesture recognizers?

This is what the function currently has, originally I had a check on the child view controller's Boolean but it ended up not being useful since it was never called. The variable viewControllers is an NSArray containing all my controllers.

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    if ([viewControllers containsObject:viewController]) {
        NSInteger index = [viewControllers indexOfObject:viewController];
        if (index < [viewControllers count] - 1) {
            return [viewControllers objectAtIndex:(index + 1)];
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: just skimmed the docs, and i don't see much alternative to overriding the gesture recognizers.  and once you have, i don't see much alternative to peeking at their action selector and overriding, which is brittle at best.  i hope somebody finds a better answer for you.  will be curious to see if there is.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was worried about. Thanks for double-checking! I checked the docs as well and I really wanted to avoid using that method because I would have to essentially rewriting their paging mechanism, which I agree would be really brittle :( I'm going to build the workflow a little differently unless there's a better way of doing this method right now.